# Chrome keyboard shortcut to create a tab group from selected tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Everytime creating a group, its `selected tabs` -> `right click` -> `Add tab to group` -> `New Group`

Is it possible to reduce it to `selected tabs` -> `Alt + G`

I searched but there isn't any default keyboard shortcut I could find.

[tab group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1Wfq.png)

Comment: came here looking for same thing. @phokat did you find any shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be a built-in shortcut for this, but the [Tab Groups Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-groups-extension/nplimhmoanghlebhdiboeellhgmgommi) extension adds this functionality. This extension was recently released to the Chrome Web Store (earliest review appears to be in 2021/04) and allows you to set shortcuts such as creating a new tab in the current group, creating a new group from the current tab or selected tabs, collapsing/expanding groups, etc.

If you install the extension, the keyboard shortcut to customize and use for your use case would be the "Group/ungroup current/selected tab(s)" shortcut.

[image]

Comment: *sigh* It's annoying that an extension is needed just to get access to keyboard shortcuts for these features.